# How to display SELECT query results to a textbox in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to allow the user to query the database for a specific `customer_id`
 and to use this to populate `textboxes(tbFName, tbLName, tbPhoneNum, etc)` with the users relevant information from the table which can then be edited on another button press update the database. Below are a copy of my current code and an image of the form i'm trying to create.

```
Public Class searchcustomers

    Dim sql As New sqlcontrol

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        If sql.HasConnection = True Then
            sql.RunQuery("SELECT order_id, date_ordered, order_total, collection_method, staff_id FROM orders WHERE customer_id=" & tbSearchID.Text & " ORDER BY date_ordered")
            If sql.sqldataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                dgvPOrders.DataSource = sql.sqldataset.Tables(0)

            End If
        End If
        'queries database to search for customer id to then display relevant data in data grid view'

    End Sub

    Private Sub searchcustomers_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearchName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearchName.Click
        If sql.HasConnection = True Then
            sql.RunQuery("SELECT customers.customer_id, order_id, date_ordered, order_total, collection_method, staff_id FROM (customers INNER JOIN orders on orders.customer_id=customers.customer_id) WHERE customers.first_name=" & tbSearchFName.Text & "")
            If sql.sqldataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                dgvPOrders.DataSource = sql.sqldataset.Tables(0)
            End If
        End If
        'queries database to search for customer name to then display relevant data in data grid view'
    End Sub
End Class
```

**FYI I've already managed to get the previous orders section working correctly.**

[image of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXo36.png)

Comment: Edit's are all well and good but i'd like some responses, even if just to tell me i'm being stupid...

Comment: why not make a string of the query command, and then display the string in a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You could run separate query to retrieve the customer information based on the customer id and use the results to populate the form. Then run the query to get the order information and populate the DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

**isit right or wrong**

```
    Dim qry As String
    qry = "select max(i.comp_id) from inventory i "
    itemcode.Text = qry
    If RS.State > 0 Then RS.Close()
    RS.Open(qry, Form1.dB)
    RS.Close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).